# Создание триггера для таблицы SQLite

Tags: sqlite, триггер

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE "test" (
    "Field1"    TEXT
);
```

Далее создаю триггер:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1 AFTER INSERT
ON test
BEGIN
SELECT* from test
END;
```

Но получаю ошибку: **Result: incomplete input
At line 1**

Для создания БД и написания запросов использую **DB Browser for SQLite**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на то, где в [документации](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) ставится точка с запятой. Ваш пример должен быть:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER t1
 AFTER INSERT
    ON test
 BEGIN
SELECT *
  FROM test; -- N.B.
   END;
```